# How can I customize the image displayed in different table view cells?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, uitableview

I'm trying to add thumbnails into cells in UITableView

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"TestThumbnail.jpg"];
```

This is what i did in 
    (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
method

However I want to add different thumbnails to each cell. Is it possible to do that?
If so, can I add name of each image(eg. "thumbnail.png") to .plist and use that to add thumbnails?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely possible to do that. If you know which image you want to appear in each row ahead of time, one approach would be to construct an array of image file names. You could read that array from a property list, specify it directly in the code, download it from a server... whatever you like. Then, use the row property of the index path to select the image for the cell at that row:

```
// somewhere in your class declaration...
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *filenames;

// somewhere in your initializer...
self.filenames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one.jpg", @"two.jpg", @"three.jpg", nil];

// in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:...
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.filenames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Glad to help. Learning to map from one set of values (like row numbers) to another set (like filenames) comes up *all the time* in programming, and there are many ways to do it. It's a fundamental skill, so make sure you understand what's going on here and look for other ways to do similar kinds of translation.